# How to display records from a table with relationship mapping in Spring boot, CrudRepository and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a simple CRUD project with Spring Boot. I have successfully accomplished connecting to the database and displaying records from ONE table. Now I want to show the "Phones" belonging to a "Client" but when I click on "VerDetalle" (http://localhost:8080/listar) it shows the table without any record (obviously the table has data)

I think the problem its with the method telefonosById(nro_cliente) of TelefonoService and verDetalle(@PathVariable Integer nro_cliente, Model model) of Controller.

"E01_cliente" and "E01_telefono" they are entities.

```
@Entity
public class E01_telefono {

    private Integer codigo_area;
    @Id
    private Integer nro_telefono;
    private char tipo;
    private Integer nro_cliente;

    @ManyToOne
    private E01_cliente cliente;

    //**Constructor and Getters and Setters**//
```

Entity E01_cliente:

```
@Entity
public class E01_cliente {

    @Id
    private Integer nro_cliente;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String direccion;
    private boolean activo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente")
    private Set<E01_telefono> telefonos;

}
```

Service Telefono:

```
@Service
public class TelefonoService implements IServiceTelefono {

    @Autowired
    private ITelefono telData;


    @Override
    public List<E01_telefono> AllPhones() {
        return (List<E01_telefono>) telData.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<E01_telefono> telefonosById(Integer nro_cliente) {
        return telData.findById(nro_cliente);


    }
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class Controlador {

    @Autowired
    private IServiceCliente serviceCliente;

    @Autowired
    private IServiceTelefono serviceTelefono;


    @GetMapping("/listar")
    public String listarClientes(Model model){
        List<E01_cliente> clientes = serviceCliente.listarClientes();
        model.addAttribute("clientes", clientes);
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/agregarCliente")
    public String agregarCliente(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("cliente", new E01_cliente());
        //Cuando el usuario presione se mostrara el formulario correspondiente al Cliente
        return "formulario";
    }

    @PostMapping("/guardarCliente")
    public String guardarCliente(Model model, @Valid E01_cliente cliente){
        serviceCliente.guardarCliente(cliente);
        return "redirect:/listar";
    }

    @GetMapping("/editarCliente/{nro_cliente}")
    public String editarCliente(@PathVariable Integer nro_cliente, Model model ){
        Optional<E01_cliente> clientEdit = serviceCliente.listarId(nro_cliente);
        model.addAttribute("cliente", clientEdit);
        return "formulario";
    }

    @GetMapping("/eliminarCliente/{nro_cliente}")
    public String borrarCliente(Model model, @PathVariable Integer nro_cliente){
        serviceCliente.eliminarCliente(nro_cliente);
        return "redirect:/listar";
    }

    @GetMapping("/verDetalle/{nro_cliente}")
    public String verDetalle(@PathVariable Integer nro_cliente, Model model){

        Optional<E01_telefono> telefonosCliente = serviceTelefono.telefonosById(nro_cliente);

        if(telefonosCliente.isPresent()) {
            model.addAttribute("telefonos", telefonosCliente);
        }
        return "detalleCliente";
    }
}
```

HTML Thymeleaf "detalleCliente.html":

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-4">

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código Área</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Número Cliente</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="telefono:${telefonos}">
                <td th:text="${telefono.codigo_area}"></td>
                <td th:text="${telefono.nro_telefono}"></td>
                <td th:text="${telefono.tipo}"></td>
                <td th:text="${telefono.nro_cliente}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put **E01_cliente cliente** from **telefonosCliente** to **${telefonos}** try change

```
model.addAttribute("telefonos", telefonosCliente);
```

To

```
model.addAttribute("telefonos", telefonosCliente.get().getClientes());
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work. How can I extract records from the database with the findById() method of the CrudRepository and store them in a List

Comment: Did you try to change fetch type for these entities to eager? In some version of hibernate all fetch types were lazy by default.